# Running front- and backend at the same time in electron

Tags: reactjs, express, electron, electron-packager

I am trying to run my express backend simultaneously with my reactjs frontend.
Front- and backend need to be packaged into one single electron app. As I am an beginner in both react and electron, the answer may be obvious.

So the question:
**What possible ways are there to achieve described behavior?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. There must be a more elegant one but [spawning a child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for the backend in the [main process](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes) of electron did work great.